# Youtube player support fragment no longer working on Android studio 3.2 (androidx)

Tags: youtube, androidx

I just updated my Android Studio to version 3.2 and followed instructions to use androidx.

I've been using a Youtube fragment inside a Fragment activity and everything worked perfectly but, after the update, these 3 simple lines now give me the error "Cannot resolve method 'add(...)'":

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

...and when i try to use "replace" instead of "add" it says: "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment', required: 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'"

...which makes me think that the problem has to do with the new AndroidX feature.

The problem is that the add method wants the second parameter of type:

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

...but the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment returns a:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Is there a way to cast the "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" into the "androidx.fragment.app.Fragment"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed it by following the @Hosszful answer, 
I made it easy by just using this file, https://gist.github.com/medyo/f226b967213c3b8ec6f6bebb5338a492

Comment: Is this answer is different from Hosszuful's answer?

Comment: Theoretically, it's the same
Technically, this is a better execution, just import the file and you're ready to go

Answer (score 11):

Just use `transaction.replace`. Ignore the error, it'll work. Google hasn't refactored youtube api library to `androidx` yet.

Comment: Any idea on when they are going to update the library?

Comment: Last api release was on October 14, 2015 version `1.2.2`. I think they're not going to update it in near future.

Comment: Official `youtube api` is buggy. You can use customized youtube https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

Comment: how to ignore error when app is not compiling itself.

Comment: @JitendraSurve What error are you having? Mine is compiling fine.

Comment: @Bek It gives compilation error. How it is working for you?

Comment: I am experiencing similar issues with this api.

Comment: has anyone fixed this issue yet? I get wrong wrong argument

Comment: Are you sure this wouldn't create any problems in future?

Comment: Check this answer : **[Incompatible fragment type with the Youtube Player for Publishers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64489859/250260)**

Comment: I do not know how @Bek intended to ignore the error, but one method is to first cast your playerFragment as a generic Object and then into the androidx fragment. This worked for me.
`transaction.replace(frameLayoutId, (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)(Object)youTubePlayerFragment);`
If the O.P. has another way to ignore the error, I would be interested.

Answer (score 11):

Just copy the original java file (`com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment`) to your project to the same package but different class name etc. `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragmentX`, and update the extends class from `android.app.Fragment` to `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

The implementation is the same:

```
YouTubePlayerFragmentX youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragmentX.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

Tested... it's working.

Comment: Where did you find the source in order to do this?

Comment: In Android Studio just type the class name YouTubePlayerFragment, than press COMMAND+B to on mac, or choose Navigate / Declaration menu.

Comment: its full of errors, needs access to classes that are not public

Comment: what is package of your class? it must be com.google.android.youtube.player package.

Answer (score 8):

Replace **`.add`**

```
transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

with this **`.replace`**

```
transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

and copy [**this**](https://gist.github.com/medyo/f226b967213c3b8ec6f6bebb5338a492) class to your project folder (it may need to create the following folders)

> java -> com -> google -> android -> youtube -> player ->  (here name of)
>   YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX.java

[image]

then in code replace

**`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`** 
to 
**`YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX`**.

Comment: Not working, says still it needs the androidx fragment.

Comment: create a class for YoutubeLib and place it in your project check updated answer.

Comment: Then how your answer is different from above answers? Those are also working as well.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to both @Hosszuful and @Mehdi. I have followed your advice and it worked very nicely.

A few weeks after I asked this question I "translated" my app to Kotlin and, therefore, I tried to translate your answer as well.

This is what I ended up with and it's working for me.

```
package com.google.android.youtube.player //<--- IMPORTANT!!!!

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ab
import java.util.*

class YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.Provider {
    private val a = ViewBundle()
    private var b: Bundle? = null
    private var c: YouTubePlayerView? = null
    private var d: String? = null
    private var e: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener? = null
    override fun initialize(var1: String, var2: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
        d = ab.a(var1, "Developer key cannot be null or empty")
        e = var2
        a()
    }

    private fun a() {
        if (c != null && e != null) {
            c?.a(this.activity, this, d, e, b)
            b = null
            e = null
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(var1: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(var1)
        b = var1?.getBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(var1: LayoutInflater, var2: ViewGroup?, var3: Bundle?): android.view.View? {
        c = YouTubePlayerView(Objects.requireNonNull(this.activity), null, 0, a)
        a()
        return c
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        c?.a()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        c?.b()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        c?.c()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(var1: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(var1)
        (if (c != null) c?.e() else b)?.let { var2 ->
            var1.putBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE", var2)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        c?.d()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        this.activity?.let { c?.c(it.isFinishing)  }
        c = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (c != null) {
            val var1 = this.activity
            c?.b(var1 == null || var1.isFinishing)
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private inner class ViewBundle : YouTubePlayerView.b {
        override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView, var2: String, var3: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
            e?.let { initialize(var2, it) }
        }

        override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView) {}
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX {
            return YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX()
        }
    }
}
```

There may be better ways to write it down and any help on that regard would be mostly appreciated but, if anyone else was looking for the Kotlin version of this problem's solution, this code should do.

PS: I'm gonna leave @Mehdi's answer as the accepted one because he's also sharing credits with @Hosszuful and because my answer is just the Kotlin version of what they suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by following code chunk.

```
Object obj = 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
    if (obj instanceof YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)
        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) obj;
```

During debugging I found that the fragmentmanager was coming to be instance of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment only. But compiler was not able to cast it when I would write

```
(YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
```

The above code chunk (**instanceof** ) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solutions did not work, till I tried the comment from [Bek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8942811/bek): [Pierfrancesco Soffritti's android-youtube-player](http://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) that is maintained and works without a hitch.