# This cast can never be succeed. Androidx

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, androidx

I'm using androidx fragment but get always null reference of youTubeFragment and it's because of different casting.[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E-mywZ-RprhWuA0poqbLkeF64kbhh85I)

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

val youtubeFragment = 
childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.playbackYoutubeFragment) as 
com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
```

youtube fragment import is:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

my layout:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/playbackYoutubeFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.
YouTubePlayerFragment"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Is there any solution to solve that problem? or i have to change my fragment type.Actually i don't want to change my androidx fragment type. help is always appreciated.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that the object that `findFragmentById` returns is not a `YouTubePlayerFragment` or anything that can ever be cast to that type, so it makes no sense to cast it to that. Casting does not magically convert one type of object to a completely different kind of object...

Comment: yes, i know that i just want a solution for that problem.

Comment: Check whether `android.enableJetifier = true` is present or not in your `gradle.properties` https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577000/youtube-player-support-fragment-no-longer-working-on-android-studio-3-2-android

Comment: Thanks man, I will check it tomorrow. And let you know. Have a happy day.

Comment: `import android.app.Fragment;` that is problematic because that is system fragment and not support/androidx fragment.

Comment: importing android.app.fragment is deprecated.

Comment: @ecle android.enableJetifier is true in my gradle.properties.

Comment: @ecle problem is solved because of  your referring question but that's not a good solution. Android studio always gives a error but i'm ignoring it.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar what kind of error? Probably you can update it in your post..

Comment: Errorr is -> Required Fragment, Found YoutubePlayerSupportFragment

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `childFragmentManager` is from `AndroidX` package, therefore `findFragmentById`'s return type is `androidx.Fragment`.
`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` so in compile-time, these are two separate types that `cannot be cast to each other`.

The problem is `Youtube SDK` not using `androidx`. You can fix this by `enabling jetifier`, add following code to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

This will fix the problem by migrating all support classes in third party libraries to `androidx`, so your cast will succeed in runtime. However, Android studio warning will still be present - you can suppress it:

```
// CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS can be ignored - happens because Youtube SDK's fragment is not
// androidx.Fragment, but Jetifier will take care of that and cast will succeed
@Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")
```

Comment: I have the android.enableJetifier in my gradle.properties but it still doesnt work for me

Comment: same here,  my gradle.properties but it still doesnt work for me