# cannot cast androidx.fragment.app.Fragment to com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using YoutubePlayerView in fragment but when i am getting the reference of youtubeplayerview from my fragment then i am getting the error of inconvertible types. Can anyone tell me that whats wrong i am doing?

Here is my layout.xml file:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/youtube_frag"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
```

Fragment.class:

```
 myouTubePlayerView= (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_frag);
```

in this line i am getting error that cannot cast fragment into youtubeplayerfragment. Please help me.

Comment: Did you migrate your code into androidX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this link [Youtube player support fragment no longer working on Android studio 3.2 (androidx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577000/youtube-player-support-fragment-no-longer-working-on-android-studio-3-2-android)