# Incompatible fragment type with the Youtube Player for Publishers

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, youtubeplayer

I tried to add in our androidx app the last Youtube Player for Publishers v2.1.2.
To add this player we must create a new instance of `YoutubeEmbedFragment extends Fragment`.

The problem here is that this Fragment extends `android.app.Fragment` and in our application we use `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` and `androidx.fragment.app` so when I want to add this Youtube player fragment like :

```
getChildFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.player_container, youTubeEmbedFragment)
    .commit();
```

It won't compile because of

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:
>   'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeEmbedFragment', required:
>   'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'

How can we stay using support fragment but also use the library ?

Comment: Sharing link, in case you missed google result. try these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577000/3497972

Comment: @akashzincle Yes I see this post, unfortunately it's a different version and the implementation has changed since. I have edit post to share version.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using AndroidX in our app and we had the same problem:

[image]

The Youtube Player for Publishers v2.1.2. is not using AndroidX so you have tu use "Fully Qualified name" to access the class `android.app.FragmentTransaction` and use the `replace()` method that requires `android.app.Fragment` from which `youTubeEmbedFragment` extends :

[image]