# Creating custom class for YoutubePlayerSupportFragment (Kotlin) Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, androidx, android-youtube-api

In my app I have a MainActivity which has mobile navigation implemented with a navBar and all that stuff. When I navigate to a fragment there needs to be a Youtube Video Player inside. As I'm developing a one activity application so far I tried to implement the Fragment approach on the Youtube API.

I'm having issues with YoutubePlayerSupportFragment. I made it work following this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792809/13150066

But this solution is, to me, kind of shady. I'm afraid this solution will crash sometime, or will not work as the API itself would.

This is the error was having with 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
[image: Error]

And as the suggestion above suggests... I created a new custom class, YoutubePlayerSupportFragmentX which extends from the Fragment class that I have no issues with, androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, and this is it's code:

***YoutubePlayerSupportFragmentX.kt***

```
package com.google.android.youtube.player //<--- IMPORTANT!!!!

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ab
import java.util.*

class YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.Provider {
    private val a = ViewBundle()
    private var b: Bundle? = null
    private var c: YouTubePlayerView? = null
    private var d: String? = null
    private var e: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener? = null
    override fun initialize(var1: String, var2: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
        d = ab.a(var1, "Developer key cannot be null or empty")
        e = var2
        a()
    }

    private fun a() {
        if (c != null && e != null) {
            c?.a(this.activity, this, d, e, b)
            b = null
            e = null
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(var1: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(var1)
        b = var1?.getBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(var1: LayoutInflater, var2: ViewGroup?, var3: Bundle?): android.view.View? {
        c = YouTubePlayerView(Objects.requireNonNull(this.activity), null, 0, a) // and this line compiles but gives red warning
        a()
        return c
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        c?.a()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        c?.b()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        c?.c()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(var1: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(var1)
        (if (c != null) c?.e() else b)?.let { var2 ->
            var1.putBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE", var2)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        c?.d()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        this.activity?.let { c?.c(it.isFinishing)  }
        c = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (c != null) {
            val var1 = this.activity
            c?.b(var1 == null || var1.isFinishing)
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private inner class ViewBundle : YouTubePlayerView.b {
        override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView, var2: String, var3: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
            e?.let { initialize(var2, it) }
        }

        override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView) {}
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX {
            return YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my fragment class in which I implement the YoutubePlayerSupportFragmentX

***VideoPlayerFragment.kt***

```
package com.vegdev.vegacademy.ui.learning

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.*
import com.vegdev.vegacademy.R

class VideoPlayerFragment : Fragment() {

    private var link: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        arguments?.let {
            val safeArgs = VideoPlayerFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)
            link = safeArgs.link
        }

        val youtubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX.newInstance()
        val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.player, youtubePlayerFragment).commit()

        youtubePlayerFragment.initialize(resources.getString(R.string.API_KEY), object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
            override fun onInitializationSuccess(
                p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                p1: YouTubePlayer?,
                p2: Boolean
            ) {
                p1?.loadVideo(link)
            }

            override fun onInitializationFailure(
                p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
            ) {
            }
        })

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_player, container, false)
    }
}
```

***fragment_video_player.XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blackBackground"
    tools:context=".ui.learning.VideoPlayerFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried changing dependencies, I tried erasing folder "/.idea/libraries", cleans and builds, everything I could find online. The only thing that did it was the suggestion above.

So my questions are:

1. Why am I getting that error with Fragment v4?
2. Am I implementing it wrong? Because it works just fine, except for the fullscreen but I've read that it's a common issue.
3. If you've implemented a Youtube Video inside a fragment, did you use another API? Is this the only one?

Comment: I have the same problem and I am using the class created by you. Can you please tell me where to put that YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX class?  Right now I have simple added this class on my fragment level package. It crashed as soon as I launch the app. As you have mentioned, I haven't changed the package name in this class, although it was asking me refactor the package name.

Comment: Hey. You have to create a new package called "com.google.android.youtube.player" and inside that you need to put your class. If you leave that class on any other packages it wont work and probably that's what's causing the crash

Comment: how do I crate another package? I mean my app has its own package name com.mydomain.appname which has all of my code but how can I create another package name?

Comment: You right click on any package and go to New -> Package. A tiny window pops up with the current structure of the package you selected -> "com.mydomain.appname.mypackage" or something like that. Delete all that and copy paste this "com.google.android.youtube.player" without the quotes. Press enter and inside that new package put your custom youtube class! :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your class on a fragment directly over an activity such as:

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX" android:id="@+id/fragPlayer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Your activity may implements `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`, and on your `onCreate` event call to object and initializate it:

```
val playerView : YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragPlayer) as YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX
playerView.initialize(getString(R.string.YOUTUBE_API_KEY), this)
```

Remember to include your class `YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX` on the `com.google.android.youtube.Player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX` package.

In my case, I used only one API. This how it looks like:

[image: Activity Sharing screen with 2 fragments]

Comment: Hi mate. Thanks for your answer, but my youtube player is working the way I did it. All I'm asking is for an explanation of why do I have to create a custom class. Or what can I do to use the original class. The youtube API is kind of buggy on it's own and I don't want to mess around with anything. This custom class could bring problems in the future.