# Implement youtube video inside fragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

im implementin youtube video in my fragment.

but im getting this error.

```
Required type: Fragment
Provided: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
```

here is my code

**xml**

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/framelayoutvideo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_new"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/framelayoutproductinfo">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
```

**class**

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlayout, container, false);

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    if (!b) {
                        YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                        YPlayer.loadVideo("5OpGXj-wzeQ");
                        YPlayer.play();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

im getting error in this part of the code

```
transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

i cant find a good tutorial or answer about my problem.

anyone can help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: which TransactionManager do you use? built-in or from support package?

Comment: i add YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi to my libs.. youtube works in activity. but i want to implement it inside my ProductFragment extends Fragment

Comment: I was asking which `TransactionManager` you are using, not what/how do you implement lib and what do you want to achieve... are you using `getSupportFragmentManager` or `getFragmentManager`? (if this is fragment in fragment then it should be the first one)

Comment: i use getFragmentManager..  ProductFragment productfragment = ProductFragment.newInstance(productid,productname,scountryid,customersid,cname,stateid,cid);
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.container, productfragment)
                                        .addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();

Comment: have you tried with `getSupportFragmentManager`? are you using support v4 or androidx?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this in AndroidX, the replace(...) method requires androidx.fragment.app.Fragment while YouTubePlayerSupportFragment returns android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Here's an old Thread:

[Youtube player support fragment no longer working on Android studio 3.2 (androidx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577000/youtube-player-support-fragment-no-longer-working-on-android-studio-3-2-android)

Follow the link to the github page reported in the marked answer, you'll find the modified class and some clarifications.